# Use LINQ aggregator dynamically

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I'm trying to create a method that uses Linq aggregator functions, like Sum, Average and Count. I have the following code:

```
private double AgreggateDynamic<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, string propertyName, string func)
{       
    //Already tried this
    //IEnumerable<T> listEnum = list.ToList();     
    Type enumerableType = typeof(Enumerable);

    MethodInfo sumMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(
        m => m.Name == func
            && m.IsGenericMethod);

    MethodInfo generic = sumMethod.MakeGenericMethod(enumerableType);
    Func<T, double> expression = x => Convert.ToDouble(x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(x, null));
    object[] parametersArray = new object[] { list, expression };

    return Convert.ToDouble(generic.Invoke(null, parametersArray));
}

AgreggateDynamic(list, "FooValue", "Sum");
```

When I run this code, it throws an error on this line "return Convert.ToDouble(generic.Invoke(null, parametersArray));".

Error:

> Object of type 'Manager.Business.Tests.Foo[]'cannot be converted to object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Linq.Enumerable]'.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this line

```
Type enumerableType = typeof(Enumerable);
```

should be

```
Type enumerableType = typeof(T);
```

This is because the `MakeGenericMethod` arguments expect the actual generic type arguments, which in case of `Enumerable.Sum<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource>` overloads is `TSource`, i.e. the type of the **element** of the enumerable.

Second, the criteria used to find the aggregate generic method is not enough, because for instance there are many `Sum<TSource>` overloads - for `int`, `double`, `decimal` etc. What you need is to find the overload for `double`.

Third, the function is very inefficient. The `selector` func (called `expression` in your code) will be called for each element of the list. Not only that you use reflection to get the value, but also reflection to find the property itself. At least you should move the `GetProperty` outside.

All these problems can easily be solved by building the whole thing using the `System.Linq.Expressions`, compiling a delegate and invoking it, like this

```
public static class DynamicAggregator
{
    public static double AggregateDynamic<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string propertyName, string func)
    {
        return GetFunc<T>(propertyName, func)(source);
    }

    static Func<T, double> GetFunc<T>(string propertyName, string func)
    {
        return BuildFunc<T>(propertyName, func);
    }

    static Func<T, double> BuildFunc<T>(string propertyName, string func)
    {
        var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<T>), "source");
        var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
        Expression value = Expression.PropertyOrField(item, propertyName);
        if (value.Type != typeof(double)) value = Expression.Convert(value, typeof(double));
        var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, double>>(value, item);
        var methodCall = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<T>, double>>(
            Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), func, new Type[] { item.Type }, source, selector),
            source);
        return methodCall.Compile();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = list.AggregateDynamic("FooValue", "Sum");
```

**UPDATE:** As correctly pointed out in the comments, `Expression.Compile` has a significant performance overhead which basically kills the benefits of this approach. However, it's quite easy to add caching the compiled delegates and then everything is as it should be.

To do that, first I slightly refactored the initial code by separating the method build/compile part. Then adding the caching is straightforward by modifying the class as follows:

```
static readonly Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string, string>, Delegate> funcCache = new Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string, string>, Delegate>();

static Func<IEnumerable<T>, double> GetFunc<T>(string propertyName, string func)
{
    var cacheKey = Tuple.Create(typeof(T), propertyName, func);
    Delegate cachedValue;
    lock (funcCache)
    {
        if (funcCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out cachedValue))
            return (Func<IEnumerable<T>, double>)cachedValue;
        var method = BuildFunc<T>(propertyName, func);
        funcCache.Add(cacheKey, method);
        return method;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the usage of expression trees, but would like to note that there is a decent performance hit for compiling them. If you use this in production, I'd see if there's a decent way to cache the produced method.

Comment: @willaien Good point! I've did a test and yes, w/o caching we seem to lose all the benefits because of the significant compile overhead as you pointed out. But after adding a caching (which is quite simple) everything is as it should be and the method is times faster than any of the others. But let me ask you something aside - do you really need `Convert.ToDouble` or it is just because of the reflection - i.e. is the property supposed to be `double`?.

Comment: I don't know why he's using Convert.ToDouble, unless he just arbitrarily wants double regardless of the actual type (int32 or double)

Comment: @willaien Oops, my fault, I apologize for the question, for some unknown reason I was thinking your are the OP :)

Comment: Thank you! This is the most complete answer, so I'm giving it as correct. Well, this is my first time trying some code using reflexion, and I got some concepts figured out wrong, so I was calling the "return int" and converting it to double. But I'm using a switch case, because it's just more simple and easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
MethodInfo sumMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(
        m => m.Name == func
            && m.IsGenericMethod);
```

You get first from the overloads of aggregate function which could not take `Func<T, double>`

Try this instead:

```
MethodInfo sumMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(
        m => m.Name == func
            && m.IsGenericMethod
            && m.ReturnType == typeof(double));
```

Comment: And he probably needs to check the method signature more robustly.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a step back and look at the problem: (I'm guessing) you want to support aggregate functions on types known at compile time (thus the generic), but don't know what property or aggregate function they will choose.

I suggest you take an alternate approach for finding the function and simply use a switch statement, like so:

```
private double AggregateDynamic<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, string propertyName, string func)
{
    var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
    Func<T, double> propertyFunction = x => Convert.ToDouble(propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null));
    switch (func)
    {
        case "Sum":
            return list.Sum(propertyFunction);
        case "Average":
            return list.Average(propertyFunction);
        case "Count":
            return list.Count();
        case "Max":
            return list.Max(propertyFunction);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Unknown aggregate function");
    }
}
```

Trying to make it possible to find all of the aggregate functions correctly for each of them using reflection would be a nightmare. You can let the compiler resolve the messy parts for you with this.

Comment: Interesting way of thinking. Although I've posted my own answer, I like your (different) view of the problem! +1

Comment: This is much better code but unclear if he wants to take that approach. +1 though.